# Implement a Network in Network CNN model using pytorch-lightning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to implement a NiN model. Basically trying to replicate code from [d2l](http://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-modern/nin.html) Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchmetrics
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torchvision.datasets import FashionMNIST
import wandb
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import WandbLogger
wandb.login()

## class definition
class Lightning_nin(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.accuracy = torchmetrics.Accuracy(top_k=1)
    self.model = nn.Sequential(
                self.nin_block(1, 96, kernel_size=11, strides=4, padding=0),
                nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride=2),
                self.nin_block(96, 256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding=2),
                nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride=2),
                self.nin_block(256, 384, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=1),
                nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride=2), nn.Dropout(0.5),
                # There are 10 label classes
                self.nin_block(384, 10, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=1),
                nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1)),
                # Transform the four-dimensional output into two-dimensional output with a
                # shape of (batch size, 10)
                nn.Flatten())
    for layer in self.model:
      if type(layer) == nn.Linear or type(layer) == nn.Conv2d:
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(layer.weight)  
  def nin_block(self,in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, strides, padding):
      return nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, strides, padding),
          nn.ReLU(), nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1),
          nn.ReLU(), nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1),
          nn.ReLU())
      
  def forward(self, x):
      x = self.model(x)
      return x
 
  def loss_fn(self,logits,y):
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    return loss(logits,y)
    
  def training_step(self,train_batch,batch_idx):
    X, y = train_batch
    logits = self.forward(X)
    loss = self.loss_fn(logits,y)
    self.log('train_loss',loss)
    m = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    output = m(logits)
    self.log('train_acc',self.accuracy(output,y))
    return loss
  
  def validation_step(self,val_batch,batch_idx):
    X,y = val_batch
    logits = self.forward(X)
    loss = self.loss_fn(logits,y)
    self.log('test_loss',loss)
    m = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    output = m(logits)
    self.log('test_acc',self.accuracy(output,y))
  
  def configure_optimizers(self):
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(),lr= 0.1)
    return optimizer
  
class Light_DataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
  def __init__(self,resize= None):
    super().__init__()
    if resize:
      self.resize = resize
 
  def setup(self, stage):
    # transforms for images
    trans = [transforms.ToTensor()]
    if self.resize:
      trans.insert(0, transforms.Resize(self.resize))
    trans = transforms.Compose(trans)
    # prepare transforms standard to MNIST
    self.mnist_train = FashionMNIST(root="../data", train=True, download=True, transform=trans)
    self.mnist_test = FashionMNIST(root="../data", train=False, download=True, transform=trans)
 
  def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.mnist_train, batch_size=128,shuffle=True,num_workers=4)
 
  def val_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=128,num_workers=4)

## Train model
data_module = Light_DataModule(resize=224)
wandb_logger = WandbLogger(project="d2l",name ='NIN')
model  = Lightning_nin()
trainer = pl.Trainer(logger=wandb_logger,max_epochs=4,gpus=1,progress_bar_refresh_rate =1)
trainer.fit(model, data_module)
wandb.finish()
```

After running the code I am only getting an accuracy of 0.1. Not sure where I am going wrong. I have been able to implement other CNN (like VGG) using the same template. Not sure where I am going wrong. The accuracy should be close to 0.9 after 10 epochs.

Answer (score 0):

The `kernel_size` & `strides` are very big for the image size of 224. It will drastically reduce the information that is passed on to subsequent layers. Try reducing them. Also, VGG was a very carefully designed architecture.

Comment: This is not the issue. The same architecture is implemented in the book using native pytorch. We get an accuracy of 0.8 during validation. However pytorch lightning only gives a 0.1 accuracy